# Automapper - Dynamic type mapping

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

When I try to map with automapper a class generated at run-time.

```
AssemblyName asmName = new AssemblyName(string.Format("{0}_{1}", "tmpAsm", Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")));
AssemblyBuilder asmBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(asmName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder = asmBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("core");
TypeBuilder typeBuilder = GetTempModule().DefineType("MyDynamicClass", TypeAttributes.Public);
Type proxy = typeBuilder.CreateType();
var mc = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap(proxy, typeof(MyViewModel));
});

var mapper = mc.CreateMapper();
mapper.Map<MyViewModel>(Activator.CreateInstance(proxy));
```

I get the following error:

> AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException : Missing type map configuration
>   or unsupported mapping.

Despite of what the error message says, the mapping has been decleared as you can see. Any suggestion?

Comment: is there nothing more in the exception message (is usually says which mapping it's missing, between which classes basically)

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
TypeBuilder typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType("MyDynamicClass", TypeAttributes.Public);
```

Instead of:

```
TypeBuilder typeBuilder = GetTempModule().DefineType("MyDynamicClass", TypeAttributes.Public);
```

Also, check the version of AutoMapper that you are using: i tested on 6.1.1.0